# the error part pageReferenceError: res is not defined

Tags: html, node.js

I am just rendering the dashboard page after successfull login but even though credentials are correct , i am still not able to see dashboard page .

Here my server.js file code!

```
app.post("/login",async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const email = req.body.fromemail;
        const password = req.body.password;

        const useremail = await User.findOne({email:email});
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password,useremail.password);
        
        console.log(isMatch);
        const token = await useremail.generateAuthToken();
        console.log("the token part"+token);

        if (isMatch){
            res.status(201).render("dash");
        }
        else{
            res.send("invalid login details");
        }
        
        // res.send(userstatus.password)
        // console.log(userstatus.password);
        // // console.log(email+" and "+password);
        // res.render("dash");

    }catch(err){
        console.log("the error part page"+err);
        res.status(400).send("invalid");
    }
    // res.render("dash");
})
```

Comment: can you share the code in your html dashboard page?

Comment: There wasnt any issue with that . Its a static page and is working

Comment: what does `console.log(isMatch)` show? 
A suggestion, instead of debugging by logging to console, try to run your code in a debugger.

Comment: From token part , it is not getting exectuted